# What can you do with templates with zero template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I learned some time ago that you can create templates with zero parameters. While it is not possible to create them directly, you can use member templates

```
template<typename ...T> 
struct Maker {
   template<T...>
   struct HasNParams { };
};

Maker<>::HasNParams<> hnp;
```

I wonder whether this is intended to be well-formed and what you can do with these beasts. Can you pass them as template arguments, and create explicit specializations (I guess the only scenario is for the empty case then)?

Comment: Is the question just "what can you do with `SomeClassTemplate<>`?" That strikes me as pretty broad.

Comment: To be generic ? What can you do with an empty `vector` ?

Comment: @Barry you could not create them pre-C++11, and I haven't seen applications, nor articles about them. This makes me wonder whether they are an accident that you should not use in your code? Or are there uses, and what are they?

Comment: @Barry if you have many use cases and can demonstrate them, please go ahead because that would indicate that the feature is not an "accident", at least not one that will be gone soon. I will place the mark on your answer =)

Comment: I wouldn't so much say that empty templates were an explicit design goal of C++11, but rather that they emerged as part of the new variadic design, and it would have been more work to explicitly forbid these for no apparent gain.

Comment: @KerrekSB as it now seems to me, there aren't really empty templates, but just templates with a parameter pack that contains zero elements. I didn't know that it works like that. See the discussion thread in the comments on Barry's answer. So it's somewhat less "dramatic" than I thought it would be.

Comment: I think you stumbled upon the "zero" of variadic templates. Mayas have had some trouble too.

Answer (score 4):

At the risk of sounding obvious, ending recursive instantiation.

```
template<typename Arg, typename ...T> 
struct Maker : public Maker<T...>
{
   template<T...>
   struct HasNmin1Params { };
};
```

The point here is that the actual argument list to `Maker` isn't empty, but we only use N-1 arguments in `HasNminOneParams`.

Comment: Thanks, can you please make an example? I don't yet see this.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following class template:

```
template <typename... > struct typelist { };
```

This is the metaprogramming equivalent of a container. And in the same way that it is useful to have an empty `vector` or `map`, it is useful to have an empty `typelist`. That is, something of type `typelist<>`. Here are two example use-cases for such a construct.

It could be the termination condition for type recursion:

```
void foo(typelist<> ) { }

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
void foo(typelist<T, Ts...> ) {
    bar<T>();
    foo(typelist<Ts...>{});
}
```

It could be a "return" value for a metafunction, indicating a failure condition.

```
template <typename F, typename T>
struct filter_one
: std::conditional_t<F::template apply<T>::value,
                     typelist<T>, 
                     typelist<>>
{ };
```

Which is a helper we could use to write a typelist filter metafunction:

```
template <typename F, typename TL>
struct filter;

template <typename F, typename... Ts>
struct filter<F, typelist<Ts...>>
: concat_t<filter_one<F, Ts>...>
{ };
```

Both of those are very useful features of `typelist<>`, and that's just the one class template.

Comment: Hmm, but what you have there is a template instantiation with an empty parameter pack. In my example we have a template with no parameter packs, but simply zero parameters, like in `template<> struct Foo { }`, created by semantics rather than syntax (because the syntax is reserved for explicit specialization). I cannot see how I can transfer your example to my case.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb You have two parameter packs in your example. `T` is a pack of types, and an unnamed pack of `T`s. It's still empty parameter pack instantiation. Are you asking specifically about an empty value pack, of no type?

Comment: why is the second an unnamed pack of `T`s? That makes no sense to me, can you explain on that further, please?. To me it is just the expansion of `T` into a parameter list and which in my case results in 0 parameters.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Well you just didn't name it right? It's basically `template <T... Vals> struct HasNParams { };` You just have an empty `Vals`.

Comment: `template<T... Vals>` there is invalid, at least I can't see what it means. If we say `Maker<int, bool>::HasNParams<1, false>`, to what parameter does `Vals` refer - to the second or first?

Comment: `Vals...` would work like in a function template http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1e1f051b9dffb45

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Why would it be invalid? It refers to both.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Is your question then about what you would do with a heterogeneous [possibly-empty] values pack?

Comment: @JanHerrmann hmm, that makes more sense to me, actually. And Clang/GCC seem to work like that (only ICC fails to compile it). If you put your comment into an answer showing how this works with an example for the class case, I will accept it.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb msvc accepts it as well. But I have no use case. I would use `tlist<>`, `tlist<std::integral_constant<int,1>>`. I think it works because the language is designed this way.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I still don't know what it is that you're asking about.

Comment: @Barry I thought that `template<T...>` with `T` being a pack simply expands like in the other cases such as with a member function of `Maker`, `void f(T...)`. I thought that in all those cases it would be as if you wrote `void f(int, bool)` or `void f();`. But apparently that's not the case, since clang and gcc create packs, like you say.

Comment: Yeah... looking at it again, it appears to me now what you said above and I think I understand. I would accept if you would put an example that applies to the pack in my question.

Comment: What is weird is that, although according to the Standard *"The resulting list of transformed parameter types and the presence or absence of the ellipsis or a function parameter pack is the function's parameter-type-list"*, and 13.1 appear to allow the overload if the parameter-type-lists are different, Clang and GCC complain about `void f(); void f(T... t);`, saying that `f` cannot be overloaded.